# Exit condition loop BrainF*ck

Tags: loops, brainfuck

I've used the [BrainFuck Visualizer](https://brainfuck-visualizer.herokuapp.com/) to check out this small piece of code but I don't understand how the exit conditions work on the loops starting with `-`. It suddenly just stops and jumps to the next statement. Could anyone explain this to me?

```
+[----->+++<]>+.+.[--->+<]>---.+[----->+<]>.++.--.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:
Since you start at `[0]` and increment it by 1 (`[1]`), then start looping and subtracting 5 each time (going round to `[255]` again), you will hit `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]`, `[4]` as rest as you pass 4 times through the loop. When you finally land on the rest being `[0]`, that's when the loop exits. In the meantime, the second spot on the tape has reached `[103]` which gets incremented by 1 to reach `[104]` to then be printed as the first letter `h` of `hi`